# how to Combe three.js page into A-frame page

Tags: three.js, aframe

Here is a `Three.js` [Example](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Texture-Animation.html) from stemkoski, now I want to use this Texture-Animation plane or box in A-frame page, how can I Combine it.

`A-frame Version: 0.9.0`

I couldn't find any examples.

Comment: entire page chunks or just the animation material ?

Comment: Yes I just want the animation material in A-frame

Comment: So sorry to forgot the source code [link](https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/Texture-Animation.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When integrating three.js pieces into aframe, it's recommended to use custom [components](https://aframe.io/docs/0.9.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html). Here's a simple example:

**js**

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {

  // this is called upon initialization
  init: function() {
     // we'll need this later on for updating the animation
     this.animator = null

     // wait until the component is loaded
     this.el.addEventListener('loaded', e => {
            // copied straight from stemkoski's code:
            var runnerTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/run.png' );
            this.animator = new TextureAnimator( runnerTexture, 10, 1, 10, 75 ); 

            // apply the texture to our element
            let mesh = this.el.getObject3D('mesh')
            mesh.material.map = runnerTexture 
            mesh.material.needsUpdate = true
     })
  },

  // this is called before each render loop
  tick: function(time, delta) {
      // update only if animator was created
      if (!this.animator) return
      this.animator.update(1000 * delta);
  }
})
```

**HTML**:

```
<a-plane foo></a-plane>
```

glitch [here](https://glitch.com/~stack-57541824). To make it work with a glitch i had to preload the image with `a-assets` due to cors issues.

Comment: Thank you first I tried with a very sample example [link](https://glitch.com/~aframe-three),looks the texture not working, I am newbie for A-frame and three.js

Comment: @zcai i've added a glitch